# MultipartConfig annotation/servlet config

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, multipartform-data

If I use the annotation (`@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize=XXX)`) that works, but the `web.xml` variety (`<max-file-size>XXX</max-file-size>`) only seems to work when `<file-size-threshold>` is also present.

This seems wrong, am I right?

EDIT: When it does work (because I've added the `file-size-threshold` tag) and I upload a larger-than-the-limit file, I get a different exception than when I use the annotation. Definitely seems odd to me.

EDIT2: Just to add more detail, I get a `SizeLimitExceededException` when I set a max file size via the annotation, and get a `FileSizeLimitExceededException` when I set a max file size (with a 0 file size threshold to make it work at all). Both exceptions print the limit I set in the max file size in the exception message.

Comment: What is your application server / container / Servlet API implememtation?

Comment: And is anything broken / giving you trouble? Or you are just wondering why `web.xml` and annotations yields different results?

Comment: im using tomcat7 and i wanted to configure that in `web.xml` instead of the annotation, but it wouldnt work unless i had `file-size-threshold`. i would consider that broken behavior, but im not the expert so thats why im asking. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the API Documentation for [MultipartConfig](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html) specifies a default value of `0`.

> ```
> public abstract int fileSizeThreshold
> ```
>
> The size threshold after which the file will be written to disk
>
> **Default:**
>     0

Unfortunatelly the `multipart-configType` (in [`web-common_3_0.xsd`](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-common_3_0.xsd)) does not specify a default value:

```
<xsd:element name="file-size-threshold"
             type="xsd:integer"
             minOccurs="0"
             maxOccurs="1">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>

      The size threshold after which an uploaded file will be
      written to disk

    </xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

I also couldn't find anything about it in [JSR 315](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/). While we could reason that `minOccurs="0"` implies that `file-size-threshold` is optional, there is nothing in the specs describing the intended behavior when this element is absent; so it is up to the vendor.

**Hint:** Try `<file-size-threshold>0<file-size-threshold>`

**Hint 2:** If it doesn't work open an issue for for the vendor (try the app Server issue tracker or the official issue tracker for whichever `javax.servlet` implementation you / they use). Do not use the word "wrong", instead go with terms such as "sensible defaults" and "metadata interoperability" (it will dramatically improve your chances):D.

Comment: thank you for the advice! i edited my original post to add more detail and ill wait around a bit to see if anyone else has anything to say. thanks!

Comment: tau. Here is my advice: 1. Read [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/bugreport.html) from top to bottom. 2. Check if the unwanted behavior is still reproducible in the latest version (Nightly Builds) 3. Bring this discussion to Tomcat mailing list (as per my initial advice, be careful about how you phrase things there). 4. Get people to agree with you (they might, at least about the inconsistent exceptions) 5. Download the latest Tomcat sources 6. Write a patch for it 7. Make sure it pass TCK 8 Open a enchantment request 9. Upload your patch 10. Profit!

Comment: While this appears daunting, trust me, it works! And it is not as hard as it sounds, even developing the patch should not be that complicated (I bet it can be done with less than 10 lines of code). You will probably spend much more time building and running tests than coding. And when you are done not only you will have accomplished something great (and gained a lot of insight into how things work), you will actually contribute to other users.